# Problem getting the direct fileserve.com download link using indy

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a problem when i try to get the direct download link using indy (delphi 2007)

I log into(fileserve.com) with my premium account successfully using this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
Data, Page : TStringList;
begin
Data := TStringList.Create;
idhttp1.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;

idhttp1.AllowCookies := True;
idhttp1.HandleRedirects := True;
idhttp1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
idhttp1.CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;
idhttp1.RedirectMaximum := 15;
idhttp1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)';

Data.Add('loginUserName=[user]&loginUserPassword=[pass]&autoLogin=&loginFormSubmit=Login');
IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.fileserve.com/login.php',Data);

idHTTP1.get('http://www.fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3');

for i := 0 to IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do
 form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Items[i].CookieText);

end;
procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
  var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: Boolean; var VMethod: string);
begin
form1.Edit1.Text := dest; //this will show the direct link after "idHTTP1.get" download the hole file
end;
```

i want to get the direct download link from this link for example fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3
but code above wil download the file then show the direct link, i don't want that i want to get the direct link without downloading the file...
fileserve redirect from http://www.fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3 to a direct link like that 
http://fs559dm.fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3/MAfrTjoMNgfT44D9-2-OTNML/22c855/hex-editor-neo.exe
i want the direct link only how i can do that please and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid downloading on a redirect, you can set `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` to False and `Handled` to True in the `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event.  The redirected URL will be in the `TIdHTTP.Response.Location` property when `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits.  For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  Data, Page : TStringList;
begin
  IdHTTP1.OnRedirect := nil;
  IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  IdHTTP1.CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;
  IdHTTP1.RedirectMaximum := 15;
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)';

  Data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Data.Add('loginUserName=[user]');
    Data.Add('loginUserPassword=[pass]');
    Data.Add('autoLogin=');
    Data.Add('loginFormSubmit=Login');
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.fileserve.com/login.php', Data);
  finally
    Data.Free;
  end;

  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := False;
  IdHTTP1.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;
  IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3');

  Edit1.Text := idHTTP1.Response.Location;
  for i := 0 to IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do
    Memo2.Lines.Add(IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Items[i].CookieText);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string; var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: Boolean; var VMethod: string);
begin
  Handled := True;
end;
```